# Laravel - loading view -> getting blank page issue

Tags: php, laravel, view

This is my class

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug = null, $slug2 = null)
    {
        if (!$slug2) { 
            $cat1 = 1;
            return view('frontend/pages/category', [
               'categories' => $cat1
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

This version of the code is working fine.
If I move the return view logic into a separate function like this:

```
        class PageController extends Controller
        {

                public function show($slug = null, $slug2 = null)
                {
                    if (!$slug2) { 
                        $cat1 = 1;
                        $this->myfunction($cat1);
                    }
                }
                public function myfunction($cat1)
                {
                        return view('frontend/pages/category', [
                           'categories' => $cat1
                        ]);
                }
         }
```

I'm getting a blank page. Nothing in the logs. Any idea why ?

Comment: Dont you need to `return $this->myfunction($cat1);` in the `show` method.

Comment: This is the route `Route::get('{slug?}/{slug2?}', 'PageController@show');`

Comment: Because argument to `myfunction` is `cat1`

Comment: @u_mulder its not that I updated my answer, srry for the mistake

Comment: After you updated your question - update code and run it.

Comment: @u_mulder still the same , blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the result of `myfunction` inside `show`

Comment: can  you be more specific ?